# Windows 8 Phone Simplest way to populate a listbox using a list<string>

Tags: c#, list, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

What is the Simplest way to populate a list box using a list. And how would you find the string tapped?

```
    List<HistoryEntry> urls = new List<HistoryEntry>();
    public HistoryEntry selectedHistory;

public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



 void Browser_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Save for fast resume
        _deactivatedURL = e.Uri;
        // We have arrived at a new page, 
        // hide the progress indicator
        _progressIndicator.IsVisible = false;
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(e.Uri).Remove(0, 11);
        getHistory(textBox1.Text);
    }

private void getHistory(string url)
    {
        HistoryEntry urlObj = new HistoryEntry();
        urlObj.url = url;
        urlObj.timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm yyyy-MM-dd");
        urls.Add(urlObj);

        listBox.ItemsSource = urls;
    }

    private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedHistory = listBox.SelectedValue as HistoryEntry;
        browserSearch(selectedHistory.url);
    }


<Grid>
                <ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding urls}" Tap="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,29" >
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding timestamp}" FontSize="15" ></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding url}" FontSize="25" ></TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
```

Once adding new values to the list, these must be then seen in the listbox and if one is tapped the program must display which value has been clicked.

Thank you in advance :)

If you need any more details please comment and I will be happy to explain in further detail :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  List<HistoryEntry> urls = new List<HistoryEntry>();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void WebBrowser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
             string url  = Convert.ToString(e.Uri).Remove(0, 11);
             HistoryEntry urlObj = new HistoryEntry();
             urlObj.URL = url;
             urlObj.timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm yyyy-MM-dd");
             urls.Add(urlObj);
             listBox.ItemsSource  = null;
             listBox.ItemsSource = urls;
        }

        public  class HistoryEntry
        {
            public string URL { get; set; }
            public string timestamp { get; set; }

        }
```

Comment: It still does not print any values from the list

Comment: did you set listBox.ItemsSource = urls;

Comment: Yes, now and also if I wanted to show the timestamp or extra details how would I add that. Do I create a second list for that or?

Comment: @user3795349 No need to create a separate list,just use the class which i have mentioned above

Comment: Okay, I have created the class now how do I add values in the MainPage and then bind to the listbox

Comment: @user3795349 Check modified answer, which shows binding  single value

Comment: It works, but whenever the getHisotry method is called it replaces the old values in the listbox. So it only ever shows one timestamp and one url.

Comment: you need to have a method to generate it without passing one url and timestamp, post the code where you want to add it to the list. please mark it as an answer if it works

Comment: `private void getHistory(string url)
        {
            List<HistoryEntry> urls = new List<HistoryEntry>();
            HistoryEntry urlObj = new HistoryEntry();
            urlObj.url = url;
            urlObj.timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm yyyy-MM-dd");
            urls.Add(urlObj);

            listBox.ItemsSource = urls;
        }`

Comment: This is the code i posted, am asking where do you have the collection of  timestamp and url. please post in ur question

Comment: What do you mean, where is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57691/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-user3795349).

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
private void WebBrowser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
             string url  = Convert.ToString(e.Uri).Remove(0, 11);
             HistoryEntry urlObj = new HistoryEntry();
             urlObj.URL = url;
             urlObj.timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm yyyy-MM-dd");
             urls.Add(urlObj);
             listBox.ItemsSource  = null;
             listBox.ItemsSource = urls;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add this in the XAML

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stack">
        <ListBox x:Name="lst">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Str}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Content="Add new Runtime" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

do it in code, if you dont want to create objects

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();

//fill your list here

foreach (string sItem in myList)
{
    ListBox1.Items.Add(sItem)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

XAML:

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="stack">
        <ListBox x:Name="lst">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Str}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Content="Add new Runtime" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

CS:

```
    Define Global `ObservableCollection<Data> obj;`

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        obj = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
        obj.Add(new Data("string1"));
        obj.Add(new Data("string2"));
        obj.Add(new Data("string3"));
        obj.Add(new Data("string4"));
        lst.ItemsSource = obj;
    }

    //For adding new values to the list, must be seen in the listbox
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        obj.Add(new Data("New Item"));
    }

public class Data
        {
            public string Str { get; set; }

            public Data() { }

            public Data(string Str)
            {
                this.Str = Str;
            }
        }
```